# What does “Humanity” mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> The time is coming, however, when he will be recognized for what he was, one of the pioneers in the slow and arduous advance of **Humanity** into that jungle of ignorance which has encompassed it so long.

Does "humanity" here mean "human race" or "quality of being humane"?

Comment: Is 'Humanity' capitalised in your source, or did you add that? (That is, uppercase 'H')

Comment: it was capitalised in my source.

Comment: I expect it means something like *civilization*.

Comment: Think about what the 'it' refers to in 'encompassed it'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey the human race?

Comment: Not *in* the jungle.  Encompassed.  Surrounded by it.   Think of it as forays into the unknown wilderness on all sides, so that it may become known and be tamed.